# JUMPSHOT/AVAST and TOR

Tags: anonymity, deanonymization

I guess that by now some of you have seen Vice's article on AVAST and how they are basically mining everything going on in your browsers. If not you can read and be afraid here: https://www.vice.com/amp/en_us/article/qjdkq7/avast-antivirus-sells-user-browsing-data-investigation

My question is if this data mining works on the TOR browser too or just the "normal" ones like Chrome, Firefox etc?

Answer (score 0):

If they were using some kind of keylogger, then they could see what you are typing into the Tor Browser. However if they were just snooping traffic, then they could see that you are using Tor but they couldn't see what you were doing on Tor.